# Cylindrical Glass Problem

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

I have found this question in the 2016 AMT maths competition and I was not able to solve it. I was wondering if any of you would be able to share some insight on how to solve this problem step by step.

It goes:

> A cylindrical glass of (inside) diameter 6 cm and height 11cm is filled and then tilted to a $45\unicode{xb0}$ angle so that some water overflows. How much water is left in it?

Thank you in advance for your time.
If you require further information please comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

If the diameter and the height were equal, then you would drop a half of the water.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As to not ruin the fun for anyone else who would like to attempt this problem I will not post how I completed it though.